# Is it possible to just register and collect matching UUIDs with an iphone in the background without the phone waking up?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, core-bluetooth, broadcast

I just want the phone the register matching UUIDs and collect those in the background with core bluetooth and when I wake up the phone and enter an dedicated app to see which UUIDs the phone registered. Is that even possible?
Also I read about there being a register limit of only 20 beacons. Is there a way to extend that limit?

Edit: The phone is also advertising

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can monitor beacon regions in the background. This is using the Core Location framework though, not the Core Bluetooth framework.  When a matching region is entered or exited you will receive a delegate callback if you have been granted "always" location permission.  You only have a few seconds to execute in the delegate method or a couple of minutes if you launch a long running task.

There is a limit of 20 simultaneous region registrations, however ideally all of your beacons will have the same UUID so they can be handled with a single region.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Thing is I want my phone to not just monitor but also to advertise alternately. Sorry That I didnt mention that in my op. Does that still work with core location framework? Like I said, I dont want to connect with other phones. I only want their UUIDs and advertise my UUID. Is it possible to scan in intervalls in the background because a few seconds of monitoring is too little.

Comment: You can scan continually for beacons in the background once you have registered a beacon region. If you want a phone to act as an iBeacon it needs to be running an app in the foreground. Using core Bluetooth a phone can advertise as a BLE peripheral in the background but you will need an app running on both phones for the discovery to work